# Spring Web MVC tomcat deployment issues

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat, intellij-idea, deployment

I am developing one Spring Web application with Intellij IDEA deployed to tomcat.
I met the issues below:

When I set the application context to the application name(my app) in the Run/Debug configuration page then run tomcat i can access the tomcat homepage and can see "myapp" in the manager page but can't access it.
The URL will be "localhost:8080/request" when clicking myapp in the manager page.
I have to add "myapp" to the URL as "localhost:8080/myapp/request".In this way the requested page can be accessed.

But if i removed "/myapp" from application context leaving it blank in the Run/Debug configuration page  then run tomcat i will access the requested page successfully.
The URL is "localhost:8080/request" now the same as before without "myapp".

If I just added the myapp.war file in /webapps folder the result is the same as the first scenario.

What i want is that I put the war file in /webapps folder and start the tomcat server then the page can be accessed.
Anything wrong i have done for the configuration or missed something?
Thanks in advance for the help.

This is the web.xml
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/log4j.properties</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
</listener>


<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.gif</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```